# 2560x1440 resolution in linux vm with virtualbox or vmware

Tags: macos, unix, vmware, virtualization, virtualbox

I've got a macbook air (10.8.2) and want to use an external monitor with 2560x1440 resolution with a Linux (Debian) virtual machine. I want to use the vm in fullscreen mode, with 2560x1440 resolution. Will that work in virtualbox or vmware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; I confirm Debian runs Full Screen under VMWare on Lion at 2560x1440.
[image]

Comment: ... and since Virtual Box is free to try - you can start there or just dive in. Be sure you install the virtual box guest extensions before giving up on resolution settings.